# AWS CodeBuild without Internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

We use a hybrid cloud setup where we connect to AWS services via VPC endpoints, but security forbids connections to the internet, which means no internet or NAT gateways. The documentation of AWS codebuild states that if it is bound to a VPC, it needs a NAT gateway for internet access in order to connect to other AWS services.

Does this mean we cannot use AWS CodeBuild? Or is there a way to configure it to connect via VPC endpoints?

Answer (score 4):

You only need internet access and a NAT gateway if you want to use AWS CodeBuild with AWS services that do not support VPC PrivateLink connections.

To find out which services support PrivateLink, please refer to: [AWS services that you can use with AWS PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/integrated-services-vpce-list.html)

Answer (score 4):

you can use [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-vpc-endpoints-with-codebuild.html) ,powered by PrivateLink. with this you don't need an internet gateway, NAT device, or virtual private gateway